# Unexpected result for inner product using reduce

Tags: reduce, chapel

In this code, I am calculating the angle between two vectors (`xvec` and `yvec`) by the usual [inner-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) relation:

[image]

```
var ang = 30.0 * (pi / 180.0);

var xvec = [3.0, 0.0],
    yvec = [cos(ang), sin(ang)] * 10.0;

var norm1sq = (+ reduce xvec**2),
    norm2sq = (+ reduce yvec**2),
    prod    = (+ reduce xvec * yvec);

var ang_out = acos(prod / sqrt(norm1sq * norm2sq));

writeln("ang_out (in degrees) = ", ang_out * (180.0 / pi));
```

My expected result is `ang_out` = 30 degrees, but in fact I get this output (with chapel-1.20.0):

```
ang_out (in degrees) = 30.0 60.0
```

So I am wondering where this "60 degrees" comes from...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+ reduce` in the line below takes precedence over the `*`, so we end up doing a reduction on `xvec` followed by a promoted multiplication with `yvec`, making `prod` a tuple of reals:

```
// same as: (+ reduce xvec) * yvec;
prod    = (+ reduce xvec * yvec);
```

To fix, use parentheses:

```
prod    = (+ reduce (xvec * yvec));
```

Alternatively, use the `LinearAlgebra` module for the dot product:

```
use LinearAlgebra;

...

prod    = xvec.dot(yvec);
```

See the precedence table (order of operations) in the spec: [precedence-and-associativity](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/language/spec/expressions.html#precedence-and-associativity)

If interested in contributing to the conversation, there is an issue about changing the order of precedence for exactly this situation: [chapel-lang/chapel#11463](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/11463)

Comment: Thanks, now I see that the problem is precedence... I am afraid this kind of (wrong) code might be difficult to debug in some cases because the code itself is "legal" (so no compile-time error...) Anyway, I will attach parentheses for safety (like "(+ reduce (...))").